# Grails 5 application is not finding GSP files in .war, grails run-app is fine

Tags: grails

I have an application that runs perfectly using `grails run-app` but fails when I try to run is using the embedded server.  I use the following commands to build and run the .war.

```
./gradlew assemble
java -Dgrails.env=dev -jar build/libs/rideshare-services-3.0.war
```

Below is the error and the steps I've taken to try to determine what the issue is.

The browser shows 500 error page, and the log shows the following:

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [grailsDispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Could not resolve view with name '/index' in servlet with name 'grailsDispatcherServlet'] with root cause
javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name '/index' in servlet with name 'grailsDispatcherServlet'
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1384)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1149)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1088)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:964)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
<snip>
```

However, spring security is enabled, and it renders its form fine with this path:

> /login/auth

So I started poking around and assets can be accessed, for example:

> /assets/advancedgrails.svg

Also, the built-in actuator paths all work fine:

> /actuator/*

I found this question
[grails and debugging UrlMappings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789523/grails-and-debugging-urlmappings) which seemed like it could help.

To test if the URL mapping were working I added a /test route in UrlMappings.groovy, mapped to a controller named 'member' and the 'index' action.
I also added the logging as suggested:

```
<logger name="org.grails.web.mapping" level="ALL"/>
```

It resolved to the correct controller and action, but still failed to load the page, so I added a log statement to the action, and the controller definitely runs, but the view fails to load.

At which point, with the debug statement in the controller, I could confirm that even without the /test URL mapping, the controller fires if I use the standard controller/action URI `/member/index`.  That confirmed that the configuration in UrlMapping.groovy was working.

So, thinking the .gsp files failed to be compiled, I searched and found this:
[Grails 3 application works locally, but unable to resolve view when deployed to a remote Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40899230/grails-3-application-works-locally-but-unable-to-resolve-view-when-deployed-to)

But I already had the plugins suggested in the answer in my build, so I figured maybe they weren't be added to the .war so I unziped it.

The .war has the gsp files as well as a mapping file `WEB-INF/classes/views.properties` which included a mapping for the view that corresponds to the controller/action I was using to test (among all of the other mappings in the file):

> /WEB-INF/grails-app/views/member/index.gsp=gsp_rideshare_services_memberindex_gsp

I then confirmed the referenced gsp_rideshare_services_memberindex_gsp files exist, and the do with the following being present WEB-INF/classes:

```
gsp_rideshare_services_memberindex_gsp_html.data
gsp_rideshare_services_memberindex_gsp_linenumbers.data
gsp_rideshare_services_memberindex_gsp.class
gsp_rideshare_services_memberindex_gsp$_run_closure1.class
gsp_rideshare_services_memberindex_gsp$_run_closure1$_closure3.class
gsp_rideshare_services_memberindex_gsp$_run_closure1$_closure3$_closure4.class
gsp_rideshare_services_memberindex_gsp$_run_closure2.class
gsp_rideshare_services_memberindex_gsp$_run_closure2$_closure5.class
gsp_rideshare_services_memberindex_gsp$_run_closure2$_closure6.class
gsp_rideshare_services_memberindex_gsp$_run_closure2$_closure7.class
```

The compiled .gsp files for all of my views seem to be here, and the source .gsp files are also in WEB-INF/classes, in the same folder structure as the project's grails-app/views directory.

So at this point I'm at a loss to understand why my views (gsp files) are not being found, although built-in views and plugin views are fine.

I will reiterate that the app runs perfectly well when run using 'grails run-app'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it is late but it might help someone along the way. Your application is failing in one environment and not on the other because the context-path is different obviously. Although this would not be the issue itself, this is just the reason for the behaviour to be different. An index action does not have a respective gsp and you are also not handling returning/redirecting from that action to account for the fact that you don't have a groovy server page to land to. The verbatim exception message says it all: Could not resolve view with name 'index' in servlet with name 'grailsDispatcherServlet']. If my assumptions are correct there should be two reasons for this, you're either redirecting to a controller that with action '/index' that doesn't exist, or you don't have a gsp to correspond with an index action that the client lands on for any reason. If my assumptions are correct the solution is easy, Search for where '/index' is being referenced and analyze if you are using a wrong controller + action combination.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I am quite sure you are correct in that Grails can's find the gsp that corresponds to the action.  But I don't know why.  The gsp files are there, and in the standard location (views).  Everything is named correctly.

Comment: Also the core issue, which may have gotten buried in all the explanation, is that it works fine using the 'grails run-app' command, and it works fine when I build and deploy a war file to a Tomcat server (which I discovered after creating this question).  So clearly the path to my gsp files is being set incorrectly when running embedded.

Comment: SOLVED: Your comment about the environment got me thinking, and actually there was a difference.  In 'dev' the app was set to use a different port (8090) as there was a conflict on my local machine.
For whatever reason this caused the built-in views to be found, but my views weren't.  So, because you caused me to look at that again, I'm accepting the answer.

Comment: This sounds like a bug.  How did you define the port in your config?

Comment: I have an app running on an alternate port and don't have any problem, but I use the command line option.

Comment: I define it in application.yml in the development environment.  
server:
            port: 8090

Comment: Using the command line to define the port has that same issues.  I used: 'java -Dgrails.env=dev -Dserver.port=8090 -jar build/libs/rideshare-services-3.0.war'

Comment: If anyone is interested, it seems using the dev environment when running the application in the embedded server is broken.  Running in test or prod works fine: 'java -Dgrails.env=prod -Dserver.port=8090 -jar build/libs/rideshare-services-3.0.wa

Comment: I have confirmed this with a newly create app.  It is even broken with the default port, if dev is used for the environment.

Comment: @SamuelSteward that is true for me as well. Thanks for sharing.